# What is the Angular Event for binding the selected date from Calendar?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am developing Ionic 4 app with Angular. Below is my code, where I want to bind date after selecting the Calendar date. What is the event for binding the date?

```
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Select Month and Year</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (blur)="onChangeDate(selectedDate)" display-format="MMM YYYY" picker-format="MMM YYYY"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>

onChangeDate(value)
  {
    this.selectedDate = value;
    console.log(this.selectedDate);
  }
```

Comment: did you got the selected date in the console>

Comment: I got the selected date. But not the moment when I select the calendar.

Comment: I can't understand on the first glance but according to me you have written a code for listening a change function and date will be set only when changed for default you have to specify it in component .sorry if I am worng and could not answer your question if question not answered please revert me back

Comment: @Vignesh It's okay. The answer you have given below works fine. Though, ionChange may be more preferable as I am developing Ionic App. But, ngModelChange is another great solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Select Month and Year</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (ionChange)="onChangeDate(selectedDate)" display-format="MMM YYYY" picker-format="MMM YYYY"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>

selectedDate:any; 
onChangeDate(value)
  {
    this.selectedDate = value;
    console.log(this.selectedDate);
  }
```

Note : ionChange event fired when you select a date.

Answer (score 2):

`<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Select Month and Year</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (ngModelChange)="onChangeDate(selectedDate)" display-format="MMM YYYY" picker-format="MMM YYYY"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>`

The `ngModelChange` function should solve your problem

Comment: Yes, this is the solution what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **`(ngModelChange)`** instead of (blur)

```
<ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (ngModelChange)="onChangeDate(selectedDate)" display-format="MMM YYYY" picker-format="MMM YYYY"></ion-datetime>
```